# Implement Hadoop Map with JavaPairRDD as Spark Way

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have an RDD:

```
JavaPairRDD<Long, ViewRecord> myRDD
```

which is created via `newAPIHadoopRDD` method. I have an existed map function which I want to implement it in Spark way:

```
LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1L);

protected void map(Long key, ViewRecord viewRecord, Context context)
    throws IOException ,InterruptedException {

  String url = viewRecord.getUrl();
  long day = viewRecord.getDay();

  tuple.getKey().set(url);
  tuple.getValue().set(day);

  context.write(tuple, one);
};
```

**PS:** tuple is derived from:

```
KeyValueWritable<Text, LongWritable>
```

and can be found here: [TextLong.java](https://github.com/apache/gora/blob/8da648456c49866a58480a14f1e11aa4a1ac0426/gora-tutorial/src/main/java/org/apache/gora/tutorial/log/TextLong.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what tuple is but if you just want to map record to tuple with key `(url, day)` and value `1L` you can do it like this:

```java
result = myRDD
    .values()
    .mapToPair(viewRecord -> {
        String url = viewRecord.getUrl();
        long day = viewRecord.getDay();
        return new Tuple2<>(new Tuple2<>(url, day), 1L);
    })


//java 7 style
JavaPairRDD<Pair, Long> result = myRDD
        .values()
        .mapToPair(new PairFunction<ViewRecord, Pair, Long>() {
                       @Override
                       public Tuple2<Pair, Long> call(ViewRecord record) throws Exception {
                           String url = record.getUrl();
                           Long day = record.getDay();

                           return new Tuple2<>(new Pair(url, day), 1L);
                       }
                   }
        );
```

Comment: I've added original tuple class at my question. Can you provide an example with Java 7 style due to lambda expressions are not supported at my current language level?

Comment: @kamaci I Added Java 7 version.

Comment: I've implemented it as like that:

    JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, Long>> result = myRDD.values().map(
        new Function<ViewRecord, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {
          @Override
          public Tuple2<String, Long> call(ViewRecord viewRecord) throws Exception {
              String url = viewRecord.getUrl();
       long day = viewRecord.getDay();
            return new Tuple2<>(url, day);
          }
     });

I couldn't find the Pair and Record classes you mentioned. My function compiles but it throws an error: `SparkException: Task not serializable` but it seems that it is another question.

Comment: Ok i guess its my bad Record and Pair was my dummy classes. Instead you should use your ViewRecord class. In spark all classes you use in rdds have to be serializable because spark by default uses java serialization to move objects between the nodes. As pair you can use for example standard spark pair class Tuple2 it is generic serializable class. The bigger problem would be if your ViewRecord is not serializable. In this case you probably have to use some costom serialization. Btw driver program has to be serializable too.

Comment: I'll accept you answer and start a new thread about my problem.

Comment: Should I use mapToPair and pairRDD? What is the difference between RDD and map?

Comment: JavaPairRDD is subclass of JavaRDD in which are all functions which require rdd to have key and value. For example join or reduce by key can be performed only on rdds witch have key value pairs. mapToPair has to return Tuple2 class and it creates JavaPairRDD on the other hand map will just create JavaRDD.

Comment: Can you check my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112626/type-mismatch-for-reduce I could not be sure about using map or mapToPair and reduce or reduceByKey for my case.